# How to change the name of columns in mysql using a query

Tags: mysql

I have created a database

There I want to swap the name of 2 columns how I can do that using a query

Currently the table look like this

[image]

I want to change the name of the Column City to Salary and Salary to City basically I only want to swap the name of the columns
(No need to change the data)

I have tried the below

```sql
ALTER TABLE tableName RENAME COLUMN oldcolname TO newcolname datatype(length);

ALTER TABLE firsttry RENAME COLUMN City TO Salary VARCHAR(100);
```

I am getting below error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'COLUMN City TO Salary VARCHAR(100)' at line 1
```

Comment: My guess is not mysql8 yet, could it be you run an older version? Please see the suggested linked topic

Comment: @Martijn I have tried all the mentioned query

Answer (score 1):

After going many article I got the solution for this

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE oldcolname newcolname datatype(length);
```

The above will work for most of the cases

Comment: If you have NaviCat, you can use the GUI to alter the column name and look in the "SQL Preview" tab to find the code that will be executed...